# How to convert Java CRC32 checksum calculation to PHP code

Tags: java, php

I trying to convert below Java code to PHP. Kindly provide a solution for me.

```
byte[] byteArr=str.getBytes();<br>
Checksum checksumObj = new CRC32();<br>
checksumObj.update(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length);<br>
Long checksum=checksumObj.getValue();
```

Comment: Kindly provide your best attempt to do it yourself

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service.

Comment: I know it's not like that. But i confused lot , so that I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete reproducible example with Java code is helpful for such a question.

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
 
// Calculates CRC32 checksum for a string
public class CRC32Generator {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hello World!";
        CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
        crc.update(input.getBytes());
        System.out.println("input:"+input);
        System.out.println("CRC32:"+crc.getValue());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
input:Hello World!
CRC32:472456355
```

PHP offers a [function for calculating the CRC32](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.crc32.php) checksum.

```
<?php
$input = "Hello World!";
$crc32 = crc32($input);

echo 'input:'.$input;
echo " CRC32:".$crc32;
```

[Try self with PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b45b8b966085c0dd39942d008318a94ed373711c).

Comment: Thanks for your support